# Worklight 6.2.0.1 MobileWebApp version

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a WL 6.2.0.1 application where I am developing for multiple platforms.

I increase the App version every time I release. However, How can I increase it for MobileWebApp as it always comes under version 1.0.

Application-descriptor.xml:

```
<android securityTest="companyTest" version="1.0.5">
.
.

</android>

<mobileWebApp cacheManifest="no-use"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the Mobile Web environment's version as it does not have a version.

please ignore the version attribute seen in application-descriptor.xml.

Comment: Thank Idan for the clarification.